# Splice Two Lists and Output to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have two lists that contain latitude and longitude coordinates, respectively. I would like to be able to be able to write these lists to a csv file in the format of:

```
Data1, Data2, Data3, lat1, long1, lat2, long2,…,latn, longn
```

Where Data1, Data2, Data3 are other pieces of data that I need on the same line followed by latitudes and longitudes in a “spliced” format.

I have been able to generate a "spliced" string of latitudes and longitudes using:

```
",".join("%s,%s" % t for t in zip(lat, long))
```

However, when I feed this string into `csv.writer.writerow()`, it is interpreted as a single element by the csv-reading-software (Excel) when I open the csv file.

What are some code segments that might help me reach my desired result?

Comment: Show us the input, the current output and the expected output. Excel and Libreoffice both allow you to specify the data separator when you're importing so make sure it's set to a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should write all your coordinates in one row. Rest of what you want is bit unclear and probably there is better way to do it, but impossible to guess without more knowledge about your input and desirable output.

```
from itertools import chain

writer.writerows([data1, data2, data3] + list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lat, lon))) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This segment does what I hoped it would do! Could I trouble you to explain how the list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lat, lon))) of the code works? The zip object is iterable, so the chain.from_iterable is chaining together each "row" of the zip? Am I close?

Comment: yes, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` "flattens" sequence by one level. See [docs[(https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions) for more information.  `itertools` is very useful module, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. One minor detail, however - isn't it always? `writerow` takes by default an iterable as an argument i.e a list, a tuple, etc. In that case, each element in the list/iterable will be a single cell in `Excel`. To see the difference, try this:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer( some_file_handle )
coordinates_iter = zip( lat, long )
# Will write lat and long as you expect
for latlong_tuple in coordinates_iter:
    writer.writerow( latlong_tuple )
```

If instead of a list/iterable, you feed `writerow` the concatenated latitude and longitude as a string then, it writes the info in a single cell. Like so

```
coordinates_str = ",".join( "%s,%s" % t for t in zip( lat, long ) )
# Will write lat and long as a string in a single cell
for latlong_str in coordinates_str:
    writer.writerow( latlong_str )
```

@m.wasowski below suggests a pythonic way to 'chain' your lists and use `writerows` instead. I recommend it. But if you prefer to keep the nested loop approach, something like this could do the trick:

```
for row in izip( Data1, Data2, Data3, lat1, long1, lat2, long2, … ,latn, longn ):
    writer.writerow( row )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, which did give me some good insight on the workings of zips. While I acknowledge that my request was not that clear, what I needed was to be able to join the concatinated lat/long with data (which I arbitrarily called Data1, Data2, etc.) all on one row of the csv file.